# SQL WHERE abc = n returns wrong data

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

So I'm trying to find the number of rows according to the following command:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT  `increment_id` ) 
FROM  `orders` 
WHERE  `created_at` LIKE  '%2013-07%'
AND  `store_id` =1
AND  `status` NOT LIKE  '%canceled%'
```

This returns a number, say `x`.

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT  `increment_id` ) 
FROM  `orders` 
WHERE  `created_at` LIKE  '%2013-07%'
AND  `status` NOT LIKE  '%canceled%'
```

This also returns a number `x`, which is wrong. In case 1, the number should be less than in case 2, because I'm filtering more rows.

Type of `store_id` is `tinyint(4)`.

Are my queries wrong? How do I make it work as I want it to work?

PS: I have checked manually, and the number MUST be low. There's nothing skewed about the data. Not all records have `store_id`=1.

Comment: check your table data if all `store_id` =1 or not for the condition `created_at` LIKE  '%2013-07%' AND  `status` NOT LIKE  '%canceled%'

Comment: As I said, I checked the data. Th query works when `store_id = 14` or any other `store_id` we have. But not for `1`

Comment: may be in all your records `store_id` =1

Comment: No. I have checked the records, and only some of them have `store_id`=1.

Comment: Id advise recreating the query step by step, try first selecting by store_id then add an AND for created_at etc. And see if the results you get are as expected. This isnt a fix just an easier why to help you identify the problem as without seeing your data it is hard to help

Comment: try without `DISTINCT` see if you get different numbers, I'm 99% sure it is making the numbers same :D

Comment: Try checking the 'increment_id' as you are making DISTINCT COUNT over that.

Comment: @mirkobrankovic that did it. but I need only distinct values.
@peterm `DISTINCT` because `increment_id` can be the same for multiple row.

Comment: just a tip regarding your query, not directly related to the question: if you have a field with a few distinct values, always aim to use ` = 'something' `, not `LIKE '%something%'` - the former is faster

Comment: @cypherabe I am doing the former in a more sophisticated way. Consider these queries SSCCE's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because not all rows have the same `store_id` does ***not*** mean these results should be different.  If you have, for example, an `increment_id` that has three records with `store_id=1` and `store_id=14` and `store_id=99` it will appear in ALL of your queries.

Try this query to see examples...

```
SELECT
  `increment_id`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `store_id` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  `count_of_store_id_1`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `store_id` = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)  `count_of_store_id_not_1`
FROM
  `orders` 
WHERE
      `created_at`     LIKE '%2013-07%'
  AND `status`     NOT LIKE '%canceled%'
GROUP BY
  `increment_id`
```

I suspect that you will see ***every*** `increment_id` has ***at least*** one record where `store_id = 1`

Comment: So that means every `increment_id` has at least on row where `store_id`=1? Because this is most definitely not the case. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I can't answer as to whether or not you understand.  But the example query will tell you, for every increment_id, whether there are rows for store_id=1 or not.

Comment: Yes, I found the problem and fixed it! Your query saved me. :)